# C# Fluent Validation if Value is X or value is Y

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I am trying to validate a type when a related property is either "Single" or "Mixed" but not when its "Double"

```
 RuleFor(session => session.SinglesMatchCount)
                .GreaterThan(0)
                .When(session => session.SessionMatchTypeId == SessionMatchTypes.Singles 
    or session => session.SessionMatchTypeId == SessionMatchTypes.Mixed);
```

This does not work. Any ideas what is the right syntax for this ?

Comment: Replace `or session =>` with `||`?

Comment: are you aiming for pattern matching, like `session.SessionMatchTypeId is SessionMatchTypes.Singles or SessionMatchTypes.Mixed` ?

Comment: @CaiusJard Yes, what is the best way to do this ?

Comment: @CaiusJard is there a way to abstract this away to a method ? There are 20+ properties that will have this validation.

Comment: Try something like `public bool IsSessionSinglesOrMixed(SessionType session) { return session.SessionMatchTypeId == SessionMatchTypes.Singles || session.SessionMatchTypeId == SessionMatchTypes.Mixed; }` and then in your rule: `.When (session => IsSessionSinglesOrMixed(session))`

Comment: 20+ properties that are the same type? Could do with a bit more detail; it sounds like backing the properties with a collection could solve the problem, but seeing the class definiton, the 20 properties and an example of the "long hand" way you're thinking of would be great

Comment: Also, if your enum has 3 values, then testing for the one it is not is less wordy than the 2 it is: `.When(s => s.SessionMatchTypeId != SessionMatchTypes.Double)`

Comment: @CaiusJard The enum does have 3 values. The 20 properties, the first 12 are valid for values X or Y is true and the last 8 are valid if the Enum type is Z.

Answer (score 0):

> The enum does have 3 values. The 20 properties, the first 12 are valid for values X or Y is true and the last 8 are valid if the Enum type is Z.

I can't decide if there are 20'different enum or if they're all the same, but it doesn't matter much

Let's say they're all the same. If your class looked like;

```
class C{

  SomeEnum[] _e = new SomeEnum[20];

  public SomeEnum Property1 {
    get => _e[0];
    set => _e[0] = value;
  }

  public SomeEnum Property2 {
    get => _e[1];
    set => _e[1] = value;
  }
  ...
  public SomeEnum Property20 {
    get => _e[19];
    set => _e[19] = value;
  }
```

}

Then you can have a method

```
bool IsValid(){
  return _e.Take(12).All(e => e != SomeEnum.Z) && _e.Skip(12).All(e => e == SomeEnum.Z);
}
```

And you can call

```
.When(c => c.IsValid())
```

---

If your enums are different types you can make the array as int[] instead and cast. For checking in IsValid make sure the Z enum has the same value in every enum (eg 2)